# styling in mat dialog in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

I am working on an angular application and using angular material `MatDialogModule`.

I have followed the [material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples) and tried using the same code in my app. The documentation doesn't have any styling .css file. But the data is well arranged.

When I tried to use the same code in my app, it's not arranged. Does `MatDialogModule` have any default styling or is the documentation skipping the styling part of code?

Dialog box as per the documentation

[image]

Dialog box when I use the same code

[image]

Comment: Is this coming as a dialog?

Comment: yes @JijoCleetus

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rxlrvllbnpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-data-example-dialog.html this is the stackblitz url for the same dialog. Please go through it

Comment: There is no css file in the app folder. Should he styling of `styles.scss` be considered?

Comment: You don't need to use any seperate css since you are importing a UI component in your component using below code.

`import {MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';`
This MatDialog having built in styles

Comment: I have used the same code as in documentation but styling is messed up. I am not sure where the scroller is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You might forget the import style at `style.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

and google font style in `index.html`

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&display=block" rel="stylesheet">
```